# Property change event's old value for collections when element is added

Tags: java, javabeans, propertychangelistener, propertychangesupport

I have a Java bean that has a collection property with a getter and also provides add methods for the collection.

So when the collection is modified using the `add` method I must fire a `PropertyChangeEvent`. A `PropertyChangeEvent` has an old value and a new value.

How do you handle the old value?

To make things easy I will use a collection of `String`s here. E.g.

```
public class MyBean {

    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private Set<String> names = new HashSet();

    // Delegate methods to add/remove PropertyChangeListeners are omitted here

    /**
     * The collection property
     */
    public Collection<String> getNames() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(names);
    }

    public void addName(String name){
          if(names.add(name)){
             Collection<String> oldValue = ????; // How do you get the old value
             Collection<String> newValue = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(names);
             pcs.firePropertyChange("names", oldValue, newValue);
          }
      }
}
```

One way to get the old value might be to create a copy before adding

```
public void addName(String name) {
    Collection<String> oldValue = new HashSet<>(names);
    if (names.add(name)) {
        Collection<String> newValue = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(names);
        pcs.firePropertyChange("names", oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

But in a lot of situations the old value might be copied for nothing.

So another thought was not to use the add method and instead use `contains` before

```
public void addName(String name) {
    if (names.contains(name)) {
        return;
    }

    Collection<String> oldValue = new HashSet<>(names);
    names.add(name);
    Collection<String> newValue = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(names);

    pcs.firePropertyChange("names", oldValue, newValue);
}
```

This works well with a `Set`. But when the `names` collection is an `ArrayList` it will not work, because an `ArrayList` can contain multiple instances of equal objects. So `contains` would return true, but an `add` would also return `true`.

In multi-threaded environments it might also be a problem to first check via contains and then add, because in the meanwhile another thread might have added the same object. But I don't want to introduce this complexity here. I just want to find a good design for a single threaded environment, usually when such beans are used in the UI (Event-Dispatch-Thread).

How do you handle the old value in such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Map.putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V) implementation, and have the key and value to be the same.

In case the key existed, the previous (old) value will be returned, and be used for firing the `firePropertyChange`.
That works well in multithreaded environment, only one thread will be able to add a new entry.